# What is good practice for nested function's return error?

Tags: go

In Go, assume that I write a function which calls several functions which return the `error` type.

1. Which one is a better practice

   - inside my function, check the return error of each called function, immediately after it returns, and panic if the return
     error is not nil
   - make my function return the `error` type, depending on whether there is an called function inside returning non-nil error, and when
     my function is called and finishes running, check its return error
     and panic if the return error is not nil.
   - both

   In my current implementation of my function, I actually do both. But
   I think it might be redundant to do so, since if a panic happens
   right after a called function returns a non-nil error, the panic
   will be handled immediately, and my function will never reach the
   step to return error.

   If I am correct that doing both is redundant, is it correct that it
   is better to check the error earlier than later, i.e. is it better
   to check the return error of each called function immediately after
   it returns, than to check the return error of my function which is
   the caller?
2. Which one is a better practice

   - use the same object of `error` to store the returns of the called functions,
   - create a different object of `error` to store the return of different called function?

Thanks.

Comment: There was a relevant gophercon talk this year. I can't find the slides, but here's the author's blog post covering the same material: http://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully *edit* heh I independently linked the same reference as the dupe :)

Comment: I generally only use panics for unrecoverable errors.  Otherwise, the "go way" is to check if err != nil {return err} or whatever the return signature dictates.